# Neo4j 3.3.3 Community version failed to install-service in Windows

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j3.3.3 community edition, while trying to install-service its show below error. Tried on different machines. How to resolve this?

I am using Java version 1.8.0_162
I have JAVA_HOME environment variable set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin

### Error:

---

Invoke-Neo4j : Unable to determine the version of the installation at
D:\neo4j\neo4j-community-3.3.3
At line:1 char:221
+ ... t.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j install-service)
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExcep
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptio
   n,Invoke-Neo4j

Comment: imho this is more a windows (dos btw) issue than a Neo4j issue. However JAVA_HOME with a space .... bad idea. Do you have set JAVA_HOME\bin in PATH for the user running the service ?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem too, and got it right by setting JAVA_HOME to **JRE** folder, which is `C:\Program Files\Java\jre-X.X.X`.

I think `install-service` is trying to fix a jdk path by adding some postfix, which is weird and causes this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I set JAVA_HOME to JRE folder but still getting error.